# Selecting edge location for AWS Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have data in AWS S3 that want to process with an AWS Lambda function. However, these data cannot exit my country. That's not a problem with AWS S3, since I can choose a region in my country. Is it possible to select which specific edge location I want to run my lambda function with Lambda@Edge?

Comment: You want to process it with Lambda or Lambda@Edge? Lambda you can run in your region and even in your own VPC, but Lambda@Edge would distribute the Lambda to all Edge locations that your CloudFront distribution is deployed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately it's not possible to filter out edge locations from the Lambda@Edge service.

As you know, it's nature is the global distribution of compute resources that execute in any of the 150+ edge locations that make up CloudFront. So it will necessarily span outside of your country.

However, you could achieve data location compliance by writing geolocation code into your Lambda, so if was invoked from a non-compliant location ie outside of your country, it simply would ignore the request and not pull data from S3.

This would have the effect of the Lambdas filtering themselves for compliance reasons.

Most of the edge requests would presumably be from your country in any case. But this logic would prevent bots or other random invocations from causing data to be transferred out of your desired S3 region.

Comment: WaltDe's answer seems to contradict this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Lambda@Edge I'm assuming you are running Cloudfront.

In Cloudfront you can enable Geographic Distribution Restrictions.  And since Cloudfront is not serving data outside you country the Lambda@Edge will not be processing data outside your country.

[Cloudfront Geo Restrictions Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/georestrictions.html)